# grep from super slow continuous streamed log and exit once string is found without buffer

Tags: bash, unix, kubernetes, buffer, stdout

**UPDATE:**

With @Tanktalus 's answer, I realized that it was the left most `kubectl` command is buffered.

```sh
# will hang forever, because RHS pipe is broken, and LHS pipe need to send 
# the output to the pipe to realize the broken pipe, but as the buffer is 
# never filled, it's never broken
kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE | grep -q "Indicator"  

# put LHS to the background, because I don't care if it hang, I just need the log.
(kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE &) | grep -q "Indicator"
```

But I have a new problem, the following now hang forever:
`(kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE &)| tee log >(grep -q "Indicator")`

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
First of all this is not repeated with other similar questions, I have read them all. The subtle difference is that my streamed log is inactive right after the string indicator I am trying to grep.

I have a continuous streamed log output from kubernetes pod. The indicator string "Indicator" will appear in the end of the log generator application, and the log generator goes `sleep infinity`. So the log will still be streamed, but gives no new output.

I am trying use a pipe `|` to redirect my kubernetes' streamed log, then grep each line of the log, until I find the "Indicator", then I want to (immediately) exit. The commands I have tried are like:

```
# none of them worked, they all show the Indicator line, and then hangs forever.
kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE | tee test.log >(grep -q "Indicator")  
stdbuf -o 0 kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE | tee test.log >(grep -m1 "Indicator")
stdbuf -o 0 kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE | tee test.log >(grep -q --line-buffered "Indicator")
stdbuf -o 0 kubectl logs -f pod -n NAMESPACE | grep -q --line-buffered "Indicator"
```

But because after the "Indicator", there will be only one more line of log "+ Sleep infinity". I guess the output buffer from the leftmost end of the pipe is not full, and thus it's not passed to grep?

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: New problems should get new questions. But your new problem looks the same as the old one. kubectl doesn't close its stdout, so tee never finishes.

Comment: @tanktalus with that said, I realized it's not exactly same with the old one. Cuz after adding some meaning less echo command after `PATTERN` in the end of kubectl log (to flush stdout buffer), the `stream | grep -q PATTERN` will break. But `stream | tee log >(grep -q PATTERN)` will hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because `kubectl` hasn't exited that the shell doesn't continue on. If you look at the `ps` output, you'll notice that `grep -m1 ...` does actually exit, and doesn't exist anymore, but the rest of the pipe still exists.

So I suspect you'll need to invert this. In perl, for example, I would use `open` to open a pipe to kubectl, read the output until I found what I wanted, kill the child, and exit.  In C, the same thing with `popen`. I'm not sure if bash gives quite that level of control.

For example:

```
 perl -E 'my $pid = open my $fh, "-|", qw(perl -E), q($|++; say for 1..10; say "BOOM"; say "Sleep Infinity"; sleep 50) or die "Cannot run: $!"; while(<$fh>) { if (/BOOM/) { say; kill "INT", $pid; exit 0 } }'
```

You'll have to replace the stuff in the `open` after `"-|"` with your own command, and the `if (/BOOM/)` with your own regex, but otherwise it should work.